# Consuming wcf service with windows process?

Tags: wcf, static, wcf-client, wcf-hosting

I need initialize some structure in wcf service class as soon as possible after start of hosting service.

Now I host it in WinForms application and there I initialize this static structure.

```
ServiceHost host = new...
host.Open()...
new MyServiceClient().Initialize();
```

But I'm sure there is better way to do this. I know now it is inelegant solution...maybe little wcf-client running as windows process? (this client  should be responsible only for calling this initializing method)

Comment: Question: why are you hosting this in a WinForms application instead of a console/Windows service?  And what specifically do you want to do in your initialization?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor of the service to do whatever initialization work is required.

```
// The service
public class MyService : IMyService {
    // Constructor
    public MyService() {
        // Initialize things here
    }
}
```

If the initialization work should only be performed once, you can make the constructor static.  If the things being constructed are not static, you can make the service a singleton, depending on your performance needs.  You can decorate the service with the following code to do that:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Comment: Look at my description once again: "Now I host it in WinForms application"

Comment: Could you give some more detail on the current setup of your services?

Comment: Service in dll, WinForms as host application. In dll I hold some objects construction. I need initialize this construction as soon as possible

Comment: You don't understand probably. When do you want fire this constructor?